# Issue with variable lifetime or scoping?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I am playing around with WCF and have a very simple WCF Service Library and Windows Application.  In the service library, I have the following:

```
Public Class Service1
Implements IService1

Dim MyRandomNumber As Integer
Dim upperbound As Integer = 50
Dim lowerbound As Integer = 1

Public Function GetData(ByVal value As String) As String Implements IService1.GetData
    Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
End Function

Public Function SendMetrics() As Integer Implements IService1.SendMetrics

    Return MyRandomNumber

End Function

Public Sub CreateRandomNumber() Implements IService1.CreateRandomNumber

    MyRandomNumber = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd())) + lowerbound

End Sub

Public Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType Implements IService1.GetDataUsingDataContract
    If composite Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("composite")
    End If
    If composite.BoolValue Then
        composite.StringValue &= "Suffix"
    End If
    Return composite
End Function
```

End Class

Very simple...  What I am testing is running a sub and then returning the value created by the sub (mainly because my application will be doing some sending and receiving and I want to test the ability to run a subroutine and the ability to return data from the service).

Now... when I run CreateRandomNumber from my userform.. and then subsequently call SendMetrics from my userform - I always get 0. :(  The random number's lifetime seems to be expiring.  I don't think it is how my form is calling it.. I have this:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim client As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim returnString As String

    returnString = client.GetData(TextBox1.Text)
    Label1.Text = returnString
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim returnString As Integer

    returnString = client.SendMetrics()
    TextBox2.Text = returnString
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    client.CreateRandomNumber()
End Sub
End Class
```

That seems correct to me.  If I put all code into the SendMetrics function, then it works fine - but this is not how my actual application will be working.

Comment: I'm thinking because it's a service library and not a real service, but exposed to the application. Just guessing.

Comment: Will you please give some more details about the WCF service??? Is it hosted in IIS? It exposes data through SOAP, REST or what?

Comment: That's all I have, though.  I created a WCF Library, created a form application as a client (all code above), then ran it in Visual Studio (which then hosts the WCF service, I think).  Eventually I'll be hosting it in a Windows Service.

Comment: You are confused. It _is_ a real service. By default, every request gets a new instance of the service class.

Comment: ok, I didn't know that.  Then when I roll this into an actual service, the service itself would keep the values I need and the successive call would retrieve those values - that should work.  Am I thinking this through correctly?  Feel free to answer below if I am and I will mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is probably a matter of configuration. In WCF you can use configuration attributes to impose the lifecycle of the Web Service instance. I suppose the [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` would be the configuration option you are looking for. It gets value from the [InstanceContextMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Using the next configuration would instantiate the service **per call**. This would lead to each variable resetting it's value on each new call.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

Using the next configuration would instantiate the service object only **once**. I suppose this would keep the variable values between successive calls of the service.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Hope I helped!